# Explain some code about dynamic connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, I'm doing a website that does a lot of things and one of them is, doing a dynamic connection string... I already did it, but because I took the code from the internet, I'm kinda lost, so I was hoping that somebody could help and explain how it works and what each thing does...

Here's the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddUpdateConnectionString("ConString");
        }



            void AddUpdateConnectionString(string name)
            {

                bool isNew = false;
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Web.Config");
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(path);
                XmlNodeList list = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(string.Format("connectionStrings/add[@name='{0}']", name));
                XmlNode node;
                isNew = list.Count == 0;
                if (isNew)
                {
                    node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "add", null);
                    XmlAttribute attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
                    attribute.Value = name;
                    node.Attributes.Append(attribute);

                    attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("connectionString");
                    attribute.Value = "";
                    node.Attributes.Append(attribute);

                    attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("providerName");
                    attribute.Value = "System.Data.SqlClient";
                    node.Attributes.Append(attribute);
                }
                else
                {
                    node = list[0];
                }
                string conString = node.Attributes["connectionString"].Value;
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder conStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(conString);
                conStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = TxtBaseDeDados.Text;
                conStringBuilder.DataSource = TxtHost.Text;
                conStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
                conStringBuilder.UserID = TxtUtilizador.Text;
                conStringBuilder.Password = TxtPalavraPasse.Text;
                node.Attributes["connectionString"].Value = conStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
                if (isNew)
                {
                    doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("connectionStrings")[0].AppendChild(node);
                }

                doc.Save(path);

            }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddUpdateConnectionString("ConString");
        }
```

Comment: "what each thing does..." That´s pretty vague and broad. Which "things" you refer to? I hope you don´t want us to explain every single line, as this may become horrible much. So what **specifically** don´t you understand? What do you **already** understand?

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting to load a connection string from the web.config file I would encourange you to use the ConfigurationManager class like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WingtipToys"].ConnectionString
```

WingtipToys would be stored like this in web.config

```
<configuration>  
<startup>   
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />  
</startup>  
<connectionStrings>  
  <add name="WingtipToys" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=WingtipToys;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

Here is more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score -1):

It creates or updates the setting in your web.config file used to store the details of how to connect to your back-end database. Config files are XML documents (which are laid out in hierarchical format), so the code finds the config, finds the right section inside of the config (creating it if it's not there), constructs a new connection string, stores it in the XML and saves the changes.